# What does this JS code do to x?

Tags: javascript, analysis

Got this little line here:

```
var x = trigger ? n : (n-1);
```

My JS is a bit rusty.
What does this do?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple ternary operator.

If `trigger` is true-like, `x` becomes `n`, otherwise it becomes `n-1`.

[Here's a page from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) showing some of the things you can do with the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

if  trigger  `true` then x becomes `n` otherwise `n-1`

The conditional operator is used as a shortcut for standard if statement. It takes three operands.

```
Condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

`condition` : An expression that evaluates to true or false.

`expr1, expr2` : Expressions with values of any types.

If condition is true, the operator returns the value of expr1; otherwise, it returns the value of expr2.

[`SEE HERE`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Comment: @ser1369594 did you understand now

Answer (score 0):

If `trigger` is [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) then `x = n` else `x = n-1`

Answer (score 0):

If condition trigger is true, then x = n. If trigger is false, then x = n - 1;

Quick tests:

```
<script>
    var trigger = false, n = 7;
    var x = trigger ? n : (n-1);
    alert( x );
</script>

<script>
    var trigger = true, n = 7;
    var x = trigger ? n : (n-1);
    alert( x );
</script>
```

More in here about "Conditional Operator":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

? is a conditional Operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Essentially it is equivalent to:

```
if (x) { x=n; } else { x=n-1;}
```

Comment: With the important difference that the operator is a expression (i.e. it has a value), where if then else is a statement.